# Does phoenix have a schema dump equivalent of Rails' schema.rb?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Rails' [schema.rb](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps) was a very convenient way to have a reference of the state of the database.  I can go straight to the pg or mysql client and describe tables to get the same info, but it's much less convenient.

Does Elixir / Ecto have a similar feature or way to generate a schema representation?

Comment: https://elixirforum.com/t/schema-file-for-phoenix-migrations/1590

Comment: Thanks, happy to mark that as an answer if you make it more than a comment :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`ecto.dump` mix task](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Dump.html):

`mix ecto.dump`